# Error when running glmnet in multinomial

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, glmnet

**The problem mentioned in this question is fixed in version 1.7.3 of the R package glmnet.**

I'm having some problems running glmnet with family=multinomial, and was wondering has encountered something similar or might be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

When I put my own dummy data in, the error "Error in apply(nz, 1, median) : dim(X) must have a positive length" gets reported when I run `cv.glmnet`, which apart from saying "it didn't work" wasn't hugely informative to me.

```
y=rep(1:3,20) #=> 60 element vector
set.seed(1011)
x=matrix(y+rnorm(20*3*10,sd=0.4),nrow=60) # 60*10 element matrix
glm = glmnet(x,y,family="multinomial")   #=> returns without error
crossval = cv.glmnet(x,y,family="multinomial")   #=> Error in apply(nz, 1, median) : dim(X) must have a positive length
crossval = cv.glmnet(x,y,family="multinomial",type.measure="class")   #=> Error in apply(nz, 1, median) : dim(X) must have a positive length
crossval = cv.glmnet(x,y,family="multinomial",type.measure="mae")   #=> Error in apply(nz, 1, median) : dim(X) must have a positive length
cvglm = cv.glmnet(x,y,family="multinomial",lambda=2)   #=> Error in apply(nz, 1, median) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Here's a visual description of the problem I was trying to get glmnet to solve, if that helps:

```
my_colours = c('red','green','blue')
plot(x[,1],x[,2],col=my_colours[y])
```

I'm able to run the example code from the package docs, which makes me suspcious that I'm either misunderstanding something or that there is a bug in glmnet.

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(10101)
n=1000;p=30
x=matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p) #=> 1000*30 element matrix
beta3=matrix(rnorm(30),10,3)
beta3=rbind(beta3,matrix(0,p-10,3))
f3=x%*% beta3
p3=exp(f3)
p3=p3/apply(p3,1,sum)
g3=rmult(p3) #=> 1000 element vector
set.seed(10101)
cvfit=cv.glmnet(x,g3,family="multinomial")
```

This is using R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08) and glmnet 1.7.1, though I can generate the same problem on R 2.14.1. Any ideas people?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a subtle bug.

What is happening is the following: In your artificial data set, the three group means are on a line, and with the relatively small standard deviation used, the three groups become linearly separable in your 10-dimensional space. As a consequence, all parameters related to the second group are estimated to 0 *for all $\lambda$*. Check

```
coef(glm)
```

Internally in `cv.glmnet` there is a call to `predict` to determine for each $\lambda$ the number of non-zero coefficients. Try

```
predict(glm, type = "nonzero")
```

The structure is, from reading the `cv.glmnet` code, supposed to be a list of lists, but the second entry in the list is NULL, and not a list! This causes the error. It happens in this block of code from `cv.glmnet`

```
if (inherits(glmnet.object, "multnet")) {
    nz = predict(glmnet.object, type = "nonzero")
    nz = sapply(nz, function(x) sapply(x, length))
    nz = ceiling(apply(nz, 1, median))
}
```

The result returned from the two nested `sapply` calls is not a matrix as expected in the last call of `apply`. This generates the error.

It might be very unlikely to run into the error in practice, but the code should of course be robust to extreme cases. You should report the problem to the maintainer, [Trevor Hastie](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/) (his email is listed at the link).

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful and quick reply. Most things you say seem to be correct, but I'm not sure the reason is necessarily that they are linearly separable. If you increase the sd of the rnorm in the inputs, the error goes away:

Comment: ... the error goes away: x=matrix(y+rnorm(20*3*10,sd=100),nrow=60) but if you reduce the input to 2 columns then error still occurs, even though the solution isn't linearly separable (can tell by eye with the plot()):
x=matrix(y+rnorm(20*3*2,sd=1),nrow=60). Still get the second list in coef() being all 0's though. Maybe I should stop messing around and put some real data in!

Comment: NRH: One thought unrelated - I suspect that Prof. Hastie may not appreciate your putting his email in plain text like that as it possibly invites spam (although it is impossible to tell for sure, of course). I don't mean to sound to harsh as your answer was very helpful..

Comment: @BenJWoodcroft, it is not linear separability as such that triggers the error but the geometric organization of the three groups along a line. The linear separability makes this organization more obvious in the sampled data, and if you increase the standard deviation sufficiently, glmnet does not "discover" the organization. As your second example shows, you don't actually need the linear separability. You are right about the email address, thanks.

Comment: In an email reply from Prof. Hastie, he advised that a new version that fixes this bug (1.7.2) will be uploaded soon. Win!

Comment: I got the same error, version 1.9-8

Comment: The code posted by the OP works fine for me (R version 3.1.0 and glmnet 1.9-8). Do you get a similar error with different code?

Comment: I am also getting this error on with glmnet 1.9.8 and with R 3.1.1 with the code above as well as the code provided on the vignette with the sample data.

Comment: I am seeing this error with real-world data using R 3.2.1 on Windows and glmnet 2.0-2. The training data has 449 observations of 229 predictors. The response variable has 9 levels. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be welcome.

Comment: I believe that you should report these errors to the maintainer.

Answer (score -2):

First convert your matrix for example

> x
>    without response into 
>   numeric
>   . After that the significant coefficient(s) that contributing to the model find by search colnames or rownames as in the data structure the variables are.